# How would you use bootstrap tabs while using an all.each do | | function in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a list of items in rails that I would like to display in Tabs, what is the best way to achieve this in rails? Below is the code.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<% State.all.each do |state| %>
<div class="btn-group btn-group" role="group">
<%= link_to state.status, tickets_path(state: state.status), :class => "panel-heading" %>
<div class="badge">
<%= state.tickets.count %>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Basically it is a list of about 8 categories which once clicked on filters the list based on the category.
Currently it displays with no tab styling. My goal is [these bootstrap tabs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#nav-tabs).

State is the category class and Status is the actual category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not building the correct structure for the tabs.

The Bootstrap documentation specifies that you should create a structure that looks like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

The structure that you're creating looks like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group" role="group">
    <a href="[ticket path]" class="panel-heading">[state status]</a>
    <div class="badge">[ticket count]</div>
  </div>
  <!-- more for each state -->
</ul>
```

What you actually want is something like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <% State.all.each do |state| %>
    <li role="presentation">
      <%= link_to tickets_path(state: state.status) do %>
        <%= state.status %>
        <span class="badge"><%= state.tickets.count %></span>
      <% end %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: This isn't relevant to the question, but I'd like to further point out that `State` is a _terrible_ name for an object.  If possible, I would recommend something more specific to your application than something generic (like State).

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! I understand now about the structure. Also about how awful and confusing State is as a object name, noted! However with your method how would the `active` class come into play? Also the badges have now moved below the item name and created terrible spacing for everything, is this something I have to resolve with CSS?

Comment: Naming things is hard.  I think I know what's wrong with the styling.  I forgot that Bootstrap does the tab styling on the a tag, not the li.  You should be able to fix that by putting the badge inside the a tag.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: As for the "active" class, that would go on the li tag.  If you follow the setup for tabs on the [JavaScript portion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tabs) of the docs, it should assign the active tag automatically when you click a tab.  The initially active tab will need to be set up manually in your template.